# AttributeError: 'tkapp' object has no attribute 'drawRectangle'

Tags: python, oop, tkinter, attributeerror

I've been trying to get my Tkinter wrapper (specialised to make a game out of) to work, but it keeps throwing up an error when it tries to draw a rectangle.
Traceback:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\William\Dropbox\IT\Thor\test.py", line 7, in <module>

    aRectangle = thorElements.GameElement(pling,rectangleTup=(True,295,195,305,205,"blue"))

  File "C:\Users\William\Dropbox\IT\Thor\thorElements.py", line 79, in __init__

    self.rectangle = self.area.drawRectangle(self)

  File "C:\Python33\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1867, in __getattr__

    return getattr(self.tk, attr)

AttributeError: 'tkapp' object has no attribute 'drawRectangle'`

The sections of the code that are relevant to the question,

```
class GameElement():
    def __init__(self,area,rectangleTup=(False,12,12,32,32,"red")):
        self.area = area
        self.lineTup = lineTup #Tuple containing all the data needed to create a line
        if self.lineTup[0] == True:
            self.kind = "Line"
            self.xPos = self.lineTup[1]
            self.yPos = self.lineTup[2]
            self.line = self.area.drawLine(self)
```

And here's the actual method that draws the rectangle onto the canvas (in the class that manages the Canvas widget), earlier in the same file:

```
class Area():
    def drawLine(self,line):
        topX = line.lineTup[1]
        topY = line.lineTup[2]
        botX = line.lineTup[3]
        botY = line.lineTup[4]
        colour = line.lineTup[5]
        dashTuple = (line.lineTup[6][0],line.lineTup[6][1])
        return self.canvas.create_line(topX,topY,botX,botY,fill=colour,dash=dashTuple)
        print("Drew Line")
```

All input is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the error stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

The error message is meant to be self explanatory. When it says `AttributeError: 'tkapp' object has no attribute 'drawRectangle'`, it means that you are trying to do `tkapp.drawRectangle` or `tkapp.drawRectangle(...)`, but `tkapp` doesn't have an attribute or method named `drawRectangle`.

Since your code doesn't show where you create `tkapp` or how you created it, or where you call `drawRectangle`, it's impossible for us to know what the root of the problem is. Most likely it's one of the following:

1. `tkapp` isn't what you think it is
2. you have a typo, and meant to call `drawLine` rather than `drawRectangle`,
3. you intended to implement `drawRectangle` but didn't